# My list items are not collapsing in navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am a little new to bootsrap, and I have tried everything for the UL class to collapse but its not collapsing when re sizing the view port. Below is the code that I have wrote.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top' role='navigation' ">
<div class="fluid" >
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>



         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Freelancer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">My Account</a> </li>
        </ul>

     </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys I just found out why. I needed to wrap the following div element around the UL

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

The code looks like this ..

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Freelancer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Account</a> </li>
            </ul>
                </div>
```